# What is the best way to perform integration test?

Tags: rebus

Is there anyway to let rebus publish all message synchronously so that I can assert on some value after all message have been processed?

Or what is the best way to do an integration test:

1. Publish event
2. handle by saga, send command
3. Handle command, publish another event
4. Saga marked as completed
5. the another event handler update the database
6. assert or database

Thanks

Regards

Yin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For testing a single saga and its behavior you should take a look at the blog post I wrote, [Unit testing sagas with Rebus](http://mookid.dk/oncode/archives/3043), which is an example on how `SagaFixture` and `FakeBus` can be used - I think it supports everything you're mentioning that you want to test.

If you're interested in testing more complicated scenarios, possibly involving other handlers and longer message correspondences etc, you might benefit from some strategic use of `ManualResetEvent` - Rebus has several integration tests that start up a bus and do some stuff, doing a `resetEvent.Set()` when the scenario is over - this way, the test can do a `resetEvent.WaitOne(timeout)` to block while the test is running and continue immediately when it's over.

Comment: Cool. I have already covered my saga with FakeBus. I am actually thinking about the ManualResetEvent (which I did a handler for this). I will have a look at the Rebus tests

Comment: Hi @mookid8000, Is there anyway to get the error queue name from rebus api? Or we have to parse the app.config manually?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's currently no public API that reveals the error queue name... I can see how it would be useful though, so it'll probably find its way into Rebus some time in the future

Comment: Cool. I currently work around this by rethrowing the exception and set the retry count to 0. Not ideal, but work for now. : )